# Excel - if cell is empty AND if cell is empty - Colour Row

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I'm a complete novice when it comes to conditional formatting.  I've found a similar question that allowed me to change the colour of the cell, but not the row.

Here's a snipped of what my sheet will look like:
[image]

So the idea is.  IF C5 AND D5 are empty - Fill whole row with red.  And I want to be able to copy that down a list of 500 rows.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative formulas (`$` or not) and set the `Applies to` range to the entire row.

Just make sure that the first row in your formula and the first row in your `Applies to` are the same.

(Screenshots show just some range example. Change to match your exact setup.)

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

Comment: That makes much more sense :)  Thank you for your help!!

Comment: @Nick if this solved your problem be sure to click the green checkmark next to it to mark it as solved